# Passing Firestore Data Through RecyclerView to Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass populated data that I'm getting through Firestore, when I press on a position on a recyclerview, onto another activity. However, I'm getting an error when I try to press on a recyclerview item. Is it because I'm passing `intent.getParcelableExtra()!!` and I need to pass something else? Thank you!

**This is the error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zwdalpha.skedaddle.Activities.Services.CategoryServiceActivity.onCreate(CategoryServiceActivity.kt:32)
```

**PopularCategoriesAdapter.kt**

```
class PopularCategoriesAdapter(val category: ArrayList<Category>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularCategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var selectedCategory = Category("", "")

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindCategory(category[position])

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
            selectedCategory.category = category[position].category
            val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, CategoryServiceActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("category", category[position].category)
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryServiceActivity.kt**

```
class CategoryServiceActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var category: Category

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_service)

// Line 32 - category = intent.getParcelableExtra("category")!!
    }
}
```

I tried switching the `intent.getParcelableExtra("category")!!` out with `intent.extras!!.get("category") as Category` but still getting the error.

Comment: "I'm getting an error" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? What are the exact errors?

Comment: I put the error message that I’m getting from the Logcat. I’m getting a NullPointException when I try going to the CategoryServiceActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not sending "category" as a object of Category().
Instead you are sending it's category field, i assume it's string.

```
//intent.putExtra("category", category[position].category)

intent.putExtra("category", category[position]) // use this
```